# Duvida Interface asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mvc, interface, repository

Boa noite, 
Estou com uma duvida, optei por trabalhar com interface generica e minha duvida é:
Toda entidade precisa ter uma interface herdando da interface generica ? 
Ex:

```
public interface IPessoaRepositorio : IRepositorio<Pessoa>
```

Ou eu crio essa interface de pessoa somente se tiver algo exclusivo dessa entidade para ser criado ?

e no meu repositorio eu criei assim:

```
public class PessoaRepositorio : Repositorio<Pessoa>, IPessoaRepositorio
```

Precisava criar assim mesmo ou bastava herdar somente de Repositorio ?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Se nem você mesmo consegue explicar o porque essa interface deve existir, é um forte sinal de que ela não deve existir.

Comment: Desculpe se pareci deselegante, mas a ideia é essa. Se vc não consegue ver o porque do criar então nem tem porque criar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisar sabe para quer server a Interface,

Os métodos formam a interface do objeto com o mundo exterior; Os botões na frente do seu aparelho de televisão, por exemplo, são a interface entre você ea fiação elétrica do outro lado da caixa de plástico. Você pressiona o botão "power" para ligar e desligar a televisão.

Na sua forma mais comum, uma interface é um grupo de métodos relacionados com corpos vazios. O comportamento de uma Pessoa em um sistema, se especificado como uma interface, pode aparecer da seguinte maneira:

```
public interface IRepositorioPessoa
{
    void Salvar(Pessoa pessoa); 
    //.....  Todo ....     
}
```

Uma classe que herde essa interface terá que implementar seu método Salvar. é como um contrato.

Na arquitetura DDD as interfaces são usadas principalmente para o desacoplamento já que você pode usar uma interface é não precisar saber quem a implementar ou como é implementada.

Na sua duvida, você se refere a  *interface genérica*, elas são usadas quando você tem um padrão pelas classe que a herda.

Por exemplo;

```
public interface IRepositorioPessoa
{
    void Salvar(Pessoa pessoa); 
    void Editar(Pessoa pessoa);
    void Excluir(int id);
    Pessoa Buscar(int id);  
}

public Class Pessoa : IRepositorioPessoa
{
   public void Salvar(Pessoa pessoa)
   {
      // Todo
   }
}
```

Aqui a classe que implementa a IRepositorioPessoa sabe que receberar uma classe do tipo pesso.

Imagine um sistema que implementa os mesmo método acima para varias classe (Pessoa, Centro Custo, Conta ...), você poderia criar uma interface genéria que tenha esses métodos não precisando duplicar criando outras interfaces.

```
public interface IRepositorio<T> where T : class
{
    void Salvar(T entidade);
    void Editar(T entidade);
    void Excluir(int id);
    T Buscar(int id);
}

public Class Pessoa : IRepositorio<Pessoa>
{
  public void Salvar(Pessoa pessoa)
   {
      // Todo
   }
}

public Class CentroCusto : IRepositorio<CentroCusto>
{
  public void Salvar(CentroCusto centroCusto)
   {
      // Todo
   }
}
```

Aqui você precisa dizer qual classe esta implementado a interface.

para um padrão você poder usar as interfaces genéricas sem problema, Agora imagine um cenário onde sua interface tem métodos específicos de um objeto uma interface genérica não seria uma boa, porque todas as classes que a herde vai ter que implementar um método particular de um objeto não fazendo sentido para elas.

Nesse caso usar uma interface própria para o objeto seria mais adequado.

Por exemplo; Vamos voltar para interface IRepositorioPessoa, imagine que você precisar de um novo método `AdicionarFilho(Pessoa pessoa)`

```
public interface IRepositorioPessoa
{
    void Salvar(Pessoa pessoa); 
    void Editar(Pessoa pessoa);
    void Excluir(int id);
    Pessoa Buscar(int id);  
    void AdicionarFilho(Pessoa pessoa);
}
```

A classe CentroCusto não teria sentido implementar um `AdicionarFilho`, por isso não seria adequado criar esse método um uma interface genérica.

Comment: Entendi, mas nesse caso eu nao poderia implementar o metodo AdicionarFilho direto no RepositorioPessoa e esse repositoriopessoa herdar do IRepositorio "generico" para implementar os metodos comuns, ao inves de ter que criar um IRepositorioPessoa somente com o método void AdicionarFilho(Pessoa pessoa) e o repositorioPessoa herdar da IRepositorioPessoa que por fim herda de IRepositorio, nao se conseguiu me entender...

Comment: @Desalex. Sim ... você pode criar o IRepositorioPessoa só com o método void AdicionarFilho(Pessoa pessoa) e herda o IRepositorio genérico. e por fim implementar tudo no repositoriopessoa

Comment: acho que vc nao entendeu, eu disse para implementar o metodo AdicionarFilho no RepositorioPessoa herdando de IRepositorio, sem precisar criar o IRepositorioPessoa, isso que quis dizer, será que posso fazer dessa forma ?

Comment: Sim, você pode, mas você perderia o poder do desacoplamento.